# Ceiling fan light will not turn off using pull cord

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

The pull cord for my ceiling fan light was broken (“stripped” so to speak) and the only way to turn off the light but still use the fan was to archanely unscrew light bulbs a bit. A new pull cord was put in. But the light still will not turn off with the new cord. All wire connections are correct. Help!

Comment: I suspect the switch is stuck in the on position from when the cord was "stripped". Follow ojait's directions but I suspect you'll find the switch stuck in the closed position.

Comment: get a smart light bulb. or one with a remote; GE makes those now as a line of "semi-smart" bulbs.

Answer (score -1):

Check for a wall switch that may have been overlooked. Also check for a remote that may control the light. Check with a voltage meter the power wire to the light (usually Blue or Black) is energized. Check the pull switch with Ohms setting to verify continuity.